# replacing $(element).offset with angular.element(element).offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I shouldn't use jQuery in my application but I got a scenario where I needed the offset of the element for which instead of using `$(element).offset()`

I have used `angular.element(element).offset()` and also for animation I am using like `angular.element(element).animate(targetPosition)` it is working properly so I wanted to know whether `angular.element()` has all the jQuery function built-in?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: If  you have loaded jQuery library then _Yes_ otherwise _No_ see [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: I have provided the cdn

Comment: but what if jqlite doesnot have the function called offset or animate

Answer (score 1):

If i have to express my thoughts on it then:

Angular does have some important jquery methods with some limitations and angular team has named it jqLite.

[Full doc for angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

This is just a case when you don't have jquery in your page then angular will use jqLite and if you load jQuery before angular then whole jQuery methods are available to use. In that case jQuery methods will be used instead of jqLite.

---

#### From the docs:

> ### Angular's jqLite
>
> #### jqLite provides only the following jQuery methods:
>
> addClass() - Does not support a function as first argument
> after()
> append()
> attr() - Does not support functions as parameters
> bind() (deprecated, use on()) - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData
> children() - Does not support selectors
> clone()
> contents()
> css() - Only retrieves inline-styles, does not call getComputedStyle(). As a setter, does not convert numbers to strings or append 'px', and also does not have automatic property prefixing.
> data()
> detach()
> empty()
> eq()
> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name
> hasClass()
> html()
> next() - Does not support selectors
> on() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData
> off() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or event object as parameter
> one() - Does not support namespaces or selectors
> parent() - Does not support selectors
> prepend()
> prop()
> ready() (deprecated, use angular.element(callback) instead of angular.element(document).ready(callback))
> remove()
> removeAttr() - Does not support multiple attributes
> removeClass() - Does not support a function as first argument
> removeData()
> replaceWith()
> text()
> toggleClass() - Does not support a function as first argument
> triggerHandler() - Passes a dummy event object to handlers
> unbind() (deprecated, use off()) - Does not support namespaces or event object as parameter
> val()
> wrap()

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs using jQLite internally, which has got all the frequent function like selectors, manipulating attributes and many more.

If you want full closer look [refer the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: what if the jqlite functions doesnot have the functions such as animate() and offset()?

Comment: If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

Comment: If jqlite doesn't got the function then just include jquery before your angular script.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.element` is simply an alias to jQuery if it is loaded. If jQuery is not loaded, `angular.element` use jqlite that contains a subset of function of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided cdn for JQuery before angularjs it will automatically use JQuery else JQLite will be used which is a subset of JQuery only. Hope this clears the understanding of the scenario.